# TinyMCE Image Uploader with Specified Upload Path

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, tinymce

I would like to know are there any ways to upload an image using local file picker in TinyMCE that we can specify the image upload path? Previously I already made a local file (image) picker, but when I upload it, the image would be stored as base64 encoded image in txt file. What I want is for the image to be saved directly to my server and for the "img src" to be the specified upload path. Anyone knows the code to do this? All helps are appreciated, thank you very much!

28/8/2021
I want to update my current code based on the answer suggested by @Dmitry D. I already set the automatic_uploads to 'true', and specified the upload directory accustomed to my local directory, but it still returns a 405 http error.

Currently I'm using TinyMCE 5.8.2 production package
I already set the FLASK_ENV = development and FLASK_APP = app

This is my index.html

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h2>TinyMCE Upload Image with Python Flask</h2>
            <form id="posts" name="posts" method="post" action="./static/tinymce/postAcceptor.php">
                <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea><br>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="./static/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea#message",
        plugins: "code image",
        toolbar: 'undo redo image',
        image_title: true,
        automatic_uploads: true,
        images_upload_url: './static/tinymce/postAcceptor.php',
        images_upload_credentials: true,
        file_picker_types: 'image',
    });
</body>
```

app.py (Flask framework)

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os
import urllib.request
 
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

postAcceptor.php

```php
<?php
  /***************************************************
   * Only these origins are allowed to upload images *
   ***************************************************/
  $accepted_origins = array("http://localhost", "http://127.0.0.1");

  /*********************************************
   * Change this line to set the upload folder *
   *********************************************/
  $imageFolder = "./static/uploads/";

  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    // same-origin requests won't set an origin. If the origin is set, it must be valid.
    if (in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], $accepted_origins)) {
      header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
    } else {
      header("HTTP/1.1 403 Origin Denied");
      return;
    }
  }

  // Don't attempt to process the upload on an OPTIONS request
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, OPTIONS");
    return;
  }

  reset ($_FILES);
  $temp = current($_FILES);
  if (is_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'])){
    /*
      If your script needs to receive cookies, set images_upload_credentials : true in
      the configuration and enable the following two headers.
    */
    // header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    // header('P3P: CP="There is no P3P policy."');

    // Sanitize input
    if (preg_match("/([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\).])|([\.]{2,})/", $temp['name'])) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid file name.");
        return;
    }

    // Verify extension
    if (!in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($temp['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), array("gif", "jpg", "png"))) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid extension.");
        return;
    }

    // Accept upload if there was no origin, or if it is an accepted origin
    $filetowrite = $imageFolder . $temp['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'], $filetowrite);

    // Determine the base URL
    $protocol = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? "https://" : "http://";
    $baseurl = $protocol . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), "/") . "/";

    // Respond to the successful upload with JSON.
    // Use a location key to specify the path to the saved image resource.
    // { location : '/your/uploaded/image/file'}
    echo json_encode(array('location' => $baseurl . $filetowrite));
  } else {
    // Notify editor that the upload failed
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error");
  }
?>
```

My directory roughly looks like this:

ImageUploader/
-app.py
-venv
-static
----uploads
----tinymce
--------tinymce.min.js
--------postAcceptor.php
-templates
----index.html

After I write flask run, and then clicked on the image button, the upload menu is there and I can browse from my local directory, but it when I try to upload it, it says "HTTP: Error 405". I tried to inspect it, and on the console menu it founds an error that said "POST http://localhost:5000/static/tinymce/postAcceptor.php 405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED)"

Anybody knows how this could happen and how to solve it? Thank you very much guys!

Answer (score 0):

The [`automatic_uploads`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#automatic_uploads) option should help. It will automatically upload images on the server and replace blob URLs with real paths to files. Here is the example of the [PHP upload handler](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/php-upload-handler/) that will upload images and give their URLs back to TinyMCE.

Comment: So should I set the automatic_uploads to True? Are there any other settings / configurations on the tinymce script? [link](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/file-picker/) --> currently I'm using the javascript mentioned in this website, but it returns with base64 encoded image. Any changes in the tinymce script I need to implement? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you need to set 'automatic_uploads' to 'true' and handle these uploads on your server. E.g., by using the above-mentioned example PHP script. If you use the basic file picker without setting up the uploads, TinyMCE still puts base64 blobs onto the page.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I still got some questions. How do I set the php script to be the one which handles the file picker? And is it possible if I use python's flask instead of php to handle it? Thanks!

Comment: Please look closely into the documentation. The answer is right in the autmatic_uploads example:
`images_upload_url: 'postAcceptor.php',`

Comment: I'm currently using python's flask as the web framework, would that cause an error if I use PHP as the postAcceptor (server side handler) ? I added my codes in the question above. Thanks

Comment: If your server also runs PHP, it shouldn't be a problem. You can try it anyway, and write your own version of postAcceptor on Python as a last resort.

The error 405 that you are getting may mean you don't actually run PHP on the server. However, there are definitely some people that could give you more precise information.